# Push to gist returning strange error

Tags: git, github, gist

I cloned a gist using the Public Clone URL. I made my changes, added, and committed. However when I run, `git push origin master` I get the following error:

```
fatal: remote error: 
 You can't push to git://github.com/1234567.git
 Use git@github.com:1234567.git
```

yet according to `git remote -v` the origin should be at the gist.github.com subdomain

```
origin  git://gist.github.com/1234567.git (fetch)
origin  git://gist.github.com/1234567.git (push)
```

Any ideas on resolving this error? Thanks!

Comment: Now no one gets to play with the editing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried changing to the remote URL that the error suggests? Try doing:

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:1234567.git
```

Currently, you're connecting with HTTP and it wants you to connect with SSH.

Comment: Thanks, I was totally missing the @ vs the //.

Comment: `git://` is a protocol specifically for git (running on port 9418), not http ... ;) You cannot use it to push because it does not support any authentication. See http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-Git-Protocol